# NETCAT TCP server/client connection not staying open

Tags: macos, unix, macports, netcat

Recently, I downloaded NETCAT on my MAC (OSX El Capitan 10.11.5) via MacPorts (2.3.4).

I created a simple TCP server with:

nc -v -l -p 3456

When I tried to connect to the server via:

nc -v localhost -p 3456

I would receive a connection open message but the connection would terminate after the client connects. I thought the connection would stay open until I hit CTRL-C or entered ^D.

Do I add a time wait for keeping the connection open on a MAC?

BTW, a friend tried the same commands on a Linux box and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different implementations of `nc` (netcat), which support different options and have to be used accordingly. Your example would not work with the netcat provided by the Mac operating system in `/usr/bin/nc`.

If the `nc` on Linux behaves differently, you should check the man page on both systems to confirm the flags and options you used are actually for the purpose you intended.

Comment: You're right @Raim. I used the MacPorts installs BSD netcat 1.10 and it's an error to use the option -l and -p together. I installed netcat via HomeBrew and the commands worked as expected because HomeBrew installed GNU netcat 0.7.1

Comment: GNU netcat is also available in MacPorts in the port gnetcat.

Comment: I saw that yesterday. Not sure how I missed that back in July. @Raim

Comment: For `nc`, flag `-k` can be used to make the server stay open; but `gnetcat` doesn't seem to have this option...